# Android customized ListView not working

Tags: java, android, class, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm creating an Android Application where the second activity shows 2 listviews, customized to show an image, two labels, and a button per row. It's a game and it shows ongoing challenges separated in sent and received.
I've read a few tutorials, all of them tell me to create an XML file to design the rows, a class for challenges, another one for the array adapter, and finally apply it on the onCreate on my activity.
However when I debug my project, the application crashes when accessing the activity containing both listviews. Here's my code, a little of it is in spanish, hope you don't mind:

Challenge Class (Partida.java):

```
    package com.example.tuneit;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.app.*;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;


    public class Partida {

    private String partner;
    private String kind;
    private String song;
    private String date;
    private String genre;

    public Partida(String partner, String kind, String song, String date, String genre) {
            //super();?
            this.partner = partner;
            this.kind = kind;
            this.song = song;
            this.date = date;
            this.genre = genre;
    }

public String getPartner() {
            return partner;
    }
    public void setPartner(String nameText) {
            this.partner = nameText;
    }
public String getKind() {
            return kind;
    }
    public void setKind(String nameText) {
            this.kind = nameText;
    }
public String getSong() {
            return song;
    }
    public void setSong(String nameText) {
            this.song = nameText;
    }
public String getDate() {
            return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String nameText) {
            this.date = nameText;
    }
public String getGenre() {
            return genre;
    }
    public void setGenre(String nameText) {
            this.genre = nameText;
    }
    }
```

Special array adapter class for Challenges (PartidasAdap.java):

```
    package com.example.tuneit;

    import java.util.List;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class PartidasAdap extends ArrayAdapter<Partida>{
    private int             resource;
    private LayoutInflater  inflater;
    private Context         context;
        public PartidasAdap(Context ctx, int resourceId,List<Partida> objects) {
            super(ctx, resourceId, objects);
            resource = resourceId;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from( ctx );
            this.context=ctx;
        }
         public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
            convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );
            Partida P = getItem( position );
                            TextView PlayerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.PlayerName);
            PlayerName.setText(P.getPartner());

            TextView fecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
            fecha.setText(P.getDate());

            ImageView imgenero = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genreIma);
            String uri = "drawable/" + P.getGenre();
        int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
        Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        imgenero.setImageDrawable(image);

            return convertView;
    }

    }
```

Activity where the listviews are displayed (menu.java). Ignore irrelevant code:

```
    package com.example.tuneit;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.app.*;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;


    public class menu extends ActionBarActivity {
        private Context ctx;
        private ListView rec;
        private ListView env;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    rec = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    env = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
    ctx=this;
    gotoReceived(findViewById(R.id.list));
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.hide();
    List<Partida> recibidas = new ArrayList<Partida>();
    List<Partida> enviadas = new ArrayList<Partida>();
    recibidas.add(new Partida("exampleUser", "rec", "Feliz cumpleaños", "13-5-2002", "other"));
    enviadas.add(new Partida("exapleuser", "env", "Feliz cumpleaños", "13-5-2007", "other"));
    rec.setAdapter( new PartidasAdap(ctx, R.layout.rows, recibidas) );
    env.setAdapter( new PartidasAdap(ctx, R.layout.rows, enviadas) );
}
```

The application didn't crash when I marked as commentaries every line except for the self-generated ones in menu.java, but neither did the customized listviews show up, so it's obvious that the problem is there.
I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the getView method from the PartidasAdap class is never invoked, but I checked this in several tutorials and neither of them used it, so I respected that.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT: after a couple weeks, I got my PC fixed and could debug your suggestions, but they didn't work. However, I now have the error log in pastebin, see http://pastebin.com/a0sYx6uk

Comment: What is the error when your app crashes?

Comment: Without the stack trace you are basically giving the keys to the mechanic and telling him "something is wrong" and walking away.

Comment: `However when I debug my project, the application crashes when accessing the activity containing both listviews.` Post the relevant xml files and the stacktrace without which its not possible indicate the cause

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate xml file as a row of your list and code inside the getView as follows

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_for_items, parent,false);

Comment: same thing for you, do I use all of this inside the getView method?

Comment: yes ,thats what I always prefer and works fine everytime

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your inflater,use this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rows, parent, false);
```

don't need to cast view.

Comment: Do I use all of this inside the getView method?

Comment: yes. replace LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_for_items, parent,false); with this

Answer (score 0):

I would code your adapter class in this way..  I am not sure you way also may be correct but this way has worked fine for me

```
public class PartidasAdap extends ArrayAdapter<Partida>{
private int             resource;
private LayoutInflater  inflater;
private Context         context;
List<Partida> objects;
    public PartidasAdap(Context ctx, int resourceId,List<Partida> objects) {
        super(ctx, resourceId, objects);
        resource = resourceId;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from( ctx );
        this.context=ctx;
        this.objects=objects;
    }
     public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_for_items, parent,false);
        Partida P = objects.get(position);
                        TextView PlayerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.PlayerName);
        PlayerName.setText(P.getPartner());

        TextView fecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        fecha.setText(P.getDate());

        ImageView imgenero = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genreIma);
        String uri = "drawable/" + P.getGenre();
    int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
    Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    imgenero.setImageDrawable(image);

        return convertView;
}

}
```